Read inserted image with "place in cell" option
I want to read images from an Excel file. These images are inserted in two ways: some are superimposed and others are inserted with the "Place in cell" option. I can now read the superimposed ones with EPPlus. I am only missing those inserted with the "Place in cell" option. I have tried with several libraries such as EPPlus, Open XML SDK, Aspose.Cell, but unfortunately I have not been successful. Has anyone had a similar experience and how did they solve it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
